# Trying to make citation with parenthesis but get only square brackets

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I want to use the following citation style

> (AuthorName, Year)

I tried to do this by using the following commands

```
\usepackage{natbib}
...
\fancyhead[LO]{Bibliography}
\setcitestyle{round}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
```

but the results is:

> [AuthorName, Year]

Because I am not that comfortable with latex, I am also adding the other packages I am using, just to make sure I am not using something that comes in conflict with the natbib package

```
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Fancy letter package
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % Fancy letter package
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
```

---

Update 1:

I forgot to mention that I am using overleaf.com for my document.

Comment: The packages you show should all be harmless and should not influence the brackets around citations, so there must be something else going on. Can you please prepare a full example document that reproduces the issue? (An MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: Do you have `\setcitestyle{round}` in the document body? I can't quite tell, but the code snippet suggests you do. Try moving it into the preamble (i.e. before `\begin{document}`).

Comment: @moewe you are right. That fixed it. I wrote your suggestion as an answer, for future readers. But if you write the answer your self, I will accept it as the correct and delete my answer. :)

Comment: Nah, it's fine. Just remember to accept your answer (when you can, I think there is a waiting time)?

Comment: But please try to provide fully compilable working examples that show the issue at hand in the future. If people have to guess the probability to get good and useful answers quickly declines.

Comment: I get what you mean. The thing is I don't yet know what is important and not in LaTeX, and I try to avoid just dumping a lot of code for others to read. But I will keep it in mind and try to give more pieces of code in the future. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ah yes, people don't want to get code dumped on them. That is very true. Just try to figure out what is important for the question. On Overleaf you can duplicate/copy your project and work on the copy. Then just remove as much from the document body as possible while still making sure the issue is reproduced. Then delete as many packages from the preamble as possible while still making sure the issue is still visible. ...

Comment: ... Deleting large parts of text/code is easy with the binary search technique (delete half of the code, see if the error persists, if so, repeat; if not add the deleted half back in and delete the other half, repeat). With binary search you only need `$O(\log_2 n)$` steps to reduce `$n$` lines of code (so about 10 steps for 1000 lines of code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution from @moewe's comment.

I had `\setcitestyle{round}` inside of `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`. After moving it before `\begin{document}`, it worked properly.

Thank you all for the effort and help.